# Binding data to an IValueConverter for a Silverlight ComboBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, combobox, ivalueconverter

I have a ComboBox that allows the user to select an hourly offset (0, 3, 6 or 9). However, what they see needs to be shown as an absolute time, which is derived by adding the offset to a base time. e.g. if the base time is "0600", the user gets to choose from "0600", "0900", "1200" and "1500".

I'm using an IValueConverter to convert this offset time to an absolute time  The base time is passed to the converter by binding a value to a custom property of the converter. (see below for the code).

Now this generally works fine except for the case of the initially selected value in the ComboBox; this always uses the default BaseTime of UtcNow, and doesn't use the bound value. By setting breakpoints in the code I can see that the BaseTime dependency property isn't set until after the call to Convert whch converts the initial value.

This is the converter class I'm using:

```
public class ForecastTimeConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
     // Register the dependency property we need for the BaseTime property.
     public DependencyProperty BaseTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "BaseTime", 
            typeof(DateTime), 
            typeof(ForecastTimeConverter),
            new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.UtcNow, BaseTimeChanged)
       );

    private static void BaseTimeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            // this method here just so I can set a breakpoint to see when the property is set.
    }

    public DateTime BaseTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(BaseTimeProperty);}
        set { SetValue(BaseTimeProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string forecast_time;
        if (value is string)
        {
            try
            {
                // get forecast period, in hours.
                int hours = System.Convert.ToInt32(value as string);
                // add forecast period to base time to get final forecast time.
                DateTime forecastTime = BaseTime + new TimeSpan(hours, 0, 0);
                forecast_time = String.Format("{0:HHmm}z", forecastTime);
            }
            catch
            {
                forecast_time = "?";
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Can't convert from type '" + typeof(ValueType) + "'");
        }
        return forecast_time;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The full XAML and UserControl source is rather large, so here are just the relevant bits:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <status:ForecastTimeConverter x:Key="ForecastTimeConverter" BaseTime="{Binding Path=CurrentBaseTime}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="forecastPeriodCombo" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" SelectionChanged="OnforecastPeriodChanged" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForecastTimeConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And the relevant code behind the XAML, simplified:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    public void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        forecastPeriodCombo.Items.Clear();
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        values.Add("0");
        values.Add("3");
        values.Add("6");
        values.Add("9");
        forecastPeriodCombo.ItemsSource = values;
        forecastPeriodCombo.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the binding of the BaseTime property of the converter isn't done until *after* the Loaded event fires for the UserControl, so the when the ComboBox is displayed, instead of seeing "0900" (3hrs offset from BaseTime) as the current value, I see something more like "17:47", (3 hours offset from UtcNow).  When I click on the ComboBox the drop-down is populated with the correct times. It's just the initial value that is wrong due to the order of events.

OnLoaded is called, ComboBox is filled, SelectedIndex is set, Convert is called, *then* the BaseTime property of the convert is set (too late!).

How can I acheive the effect I require?  Should I be populating the ComboBox on some other event? Or is there perhaps a better way to pass the basetime to the converter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define ItemsSource of you combobox via binding to get Converter work.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="forecastPeriodCombo" ItemsSource={Binding ObservableCollectionWithValues, Converter={StaticResource ForecastTimeConverter}} ... >
```

"ObservableCollectionWithValues" is property in your view model (if you use mvvm) or property in your code behind (which is actually not correct approach). If you not use mvvm then add also this.DataContext = this; in constructor of your control.

What about converter, as I know it is not possible to use binding for Resources (you can bind only to another static resource). This means your converter will not get BaseTime property set. Try to use ConverterParameter instead to pass base time to the converter.

Comment: The ItemsSource is set (in the code) and the converter does work for the drop-down part of the combo. 
The BaseTime value isn't know until run-time - how can I bind that to the ConverterParameter? I thought it was only constant values I could specify as a ConverterParameter.  This is the reason I used the binding to the converter itself (which works in general, it's just not bound before I need to use it)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but hopefully can help anyone finding this page.

Make the object (in this case CurrentBaseTime) a public Property of the View Model and make sure the view model inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. Load the values (in my case, it was a lookup table for the combobox) and then set the Property after the load (raising the property change).

Then load your model. In my case, I need three lookup tables worth of metadata to be loaded in the viewmodel and then the model to be loaded. The View then calls the converters which are prepopulated with metadata (using the Dependency Property).

The ViewModel needs to raise the Property changes otherwise the converters a stuck with null, i.e. the issue above.